# How to join lines after a condition for a text file-Python?

Tags: python, text-files

I have text file with the format below. We have multiple "context" parts with text consisting of multiple lines and topic (a one line topic). Then multiple questions with different ids about the context paragraph. I want to store context in a list. Where each context is an element of the list. My method was to take all the lines between lines that start with "context" and starts with "topic". However, once I set the condition that I want the lines between context and topic I can not join the different contexts into same string. Below is my code.

```
context : 
|

topic: 

|
question: 

answer: 

id: 
|
question: 

answer: 

id: 

|

context: 
|

topic: 

|
question: 

answer: 

id: 
.
.
.
```

```py
context =  []
f = open("example.txt","r")
context_line = True
for line in f:
  if not line.strip():
    continue
  str1 = ""
  if line.startswith("context"):
    context_line = True
  elif line.startswith("topic"):
    context_line = False
  if context_line:
    # Here how can I join the lines?
    str1 += line.rstrip("\n").lstrip("\ufeff").strip("|")
  context.append(str1)
```

Comment: How about writing your input file in JSON or YAML? There are existing, efficient and well-maintained parsers for these formats that will simplify your code, and make it substantialy easier to maintain /.extend in the future.

Comment: @a'r how about text files? Is it too hard to do in this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of all the lines in the context and join them when the topic part starts:

```
context =  []
f = open("example.txt","r")
context_line = True
for line in f:
  if not line.strip():
    continue
  if line.startswith("context"):
    context_line = True
    str1 = []
  elif line.startswith("topic"):
    lines = ' '.join(str1)  # here you can choose how to join the lines
    context.append(lines)
    context_line = False
  if context_line:
    str1.append(line.rstrip("\n").lstrip("\ufeff").strip("|"))
```

---

On a side note, just be aware that this method doesn't make any check that the input files are correctly formatted. In particular, if a `context` section is not immediately followed by a `topic` section, it will not work as intended.

Comment: I'm getting an error at the last line:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Umm... Have you changed the initialization of `str1`? There are several modifications in the code, I have the feeling you only took a part of them.

Comment: It works fine on my machine. The error you show means that `str1` has been initialized as a string somewhere, so it doesn't have the `append` attribute. In the code that I have posted, `str1` is initialized as an empty list. I don't see where it can come from... Just double check everything. And make sure you don't have other `str1` variables in the code.

Comment: This is the output I get with your example.txt template filled with some gibberish: `['context : adfskj asdfljhdfkjh hjh jkhd jhdfkjh kjh k dfs', 'context: ciao ciao sdfkj hjha hjdf aaa']`